# Localytics causing crash due to image not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, localytics

I'm trying to integrate Localytics into my iOS app and am using cocoapods:

```
pod 'Localytics'
```

However, when I start my app (I'm not even invoking or importing the Localytics namespace yet) my app blows up with this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Localytics.framework/Localytics
  Referenced from: /Users/bobbydavro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8A21B45E-D77B-41F7-AB45-8F77DE48A4AF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/556E667A-59D9-4072-81F1-B9CA600E0C46/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

I've found a number of related SO articles on this but none of the suggested fixes work:

- make the linked pods binary 'optional'
- disable bitcode
- pod deintegrate, then re-install

I'm stuck, I also tried using Segment to integrate but it has a direct dependency on the same pod and blows up exactly the same way :/

Answer (score 3):

Well, try the following:
go to `Project Setting` Your_Target -> `General` -> `Embedded Binaries` -> click on `+` button and add your library here

Comment: Just tried this but it wasn't an option. In fact only one of pods was available in the list presented (there are about 6 or so pods).

Comment: @OMK amazing, i'm glad to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

To use the dynamic framework with Cocoapods 1.0, you need to add the `use_frameworks!` statement to your Podfile.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'MyApp' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Localytics'
end
```

Comment: @Jay-Whitsitt, can you test to see if this solution will work instead of using the static framework?

Comment: Added use_frameworks and worked for me. Side effect was that I needed to change some header imports from <> to "" for some libs I am using.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me as well. For some reason, my project didn't like their dynamic framework. (I'm not supporting iOS 7 so that shouldn't be an issue.)

My fix was to use their static framework.

```
pod 'LocalyticsStaticFramework'
```

It's likely an issue with the project settings, not their framework.